# Max/min values over convex hulls.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

Let $\mathbf{v}_1,\dots,\mathbf{v}_r$ be vectors in a Euclidean space $\mathbf{V}$.

Let $f \colon \mathbf{V} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear function. Prove that
$f$ has both a maximum and a minimum value on $\mathrm{Conv}(\mathbf{v}_1,\dots,\mathbf{v}_r)$,
and show that it has both a maximizer and a minimizer in $\{\mathbf{v}_1,\dots,\mathbf{v}_r\}$.

Not sure how to prove this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It follows easily if $V$ is finite dimensional. Then any linear function is continuous and since $\text{Conv}(v_1,\dots v_r)$ is convex and compact, $f$ attains its extrema.

Comment: If $V$ is infinite dimensional, then just restrict $f$ to the (finite dimensional) subspace generated by $v_1,\dots,v_r.$ This restrictions remains linear and is continuous. The convex hull is inside the subspace, and it remains convex and compact.